# UIButton inside UINavigationController receives taps from wrong place

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

I am trying to programmatically create a UIViewController subclass whose view includes some buttons, and then add that to a UINavigationController.  When I do, you have to touch about 40 or 50 points above each button in order to trigger it (touching the buttons themselves does nothing).  The distance between the button and the actual area you have to touch seems to match the height of the UINavigationController's nav bar, so I suspect that has something to do with it.  Any suggestions on how to fix this?  Here is the code that creates the window and the buttons (from my UIViewController subclass):

```
- (void)loadView
{
    ...

    UIWindow* mainView = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]] autorelease];
    [mainView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]];
    [mainView makeKeyAndVisible];

    [self setView:mainView];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton* encryptButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [encryptButton setTitle:@"Encrypt" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [encryptButton setFrame:CGRectMake(([[self view] bounds].size.width - 150.0f)/2.0f,
                                           ([[self view] bounds].size.height - 120.0f)/2.0f, 150.0f, 40.0f)];
    [encryptButton setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 150.0f, 40.0f)];
    [encryptButton addTarget:self action:@selector(encryptPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [[self view] addSubview:encryptButton];
    [encryptButton release];

    UIButton* decryptButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [decryptButton setTitle:@"Decrypt" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [decryptButton setFrame:CGRectMake(([[self view] bounds].size.width - 150.0f)/2.0f,
                                           ([[self view] bounds].size.height - 120.0f)/2.0f + 80.0f, 150.0f, 40.0f)];
    [decryptButton addTarget:self action:@selector(decryptPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [[self view] addSubview:decryptButton];
    [decryptButton release];
}
```

Here's the code that sets up the UINavigationController:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    UUMainWindowViewController* mainWinController = [[UUMainWindowViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController* mainNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                     initWithRootViewController:mainWinController];
    [mainNavController navigationBar].barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    [self.window setRootViewController:mainNavController];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my own answer.  Turns out this was a newbie mistake where I was constructing a UIWindow in my UIViewController when I really just need to construct a UIView instead.  Apparently there should only ever be one UIWindow, so presumably this wasn't working because UIWindow was assuming it had the entire screen real estate to itself.